# A VBA program to filter a data table works on my PC but not on some others

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

My VBA filters a data table based on two values: a chosen person name and/or a type
This is the code

```vb
Sub xfilteren()

' filter the data table based on a choice for a person and/or a type

Dim mkeuze As String, mtype As String
Dim mkolom_bgl As Integer, mkolom_type As Integer

mkeuze = Range("xkeuze_bgl_filter").Value ' chosen person
mtype = Range("xkeuze_type_filter").Value ' chosen type
mkolom_bgl = Range("xkolom_bgl_pvb").Value ' calculated field column number for chosen person
mkolom_type = Range("xkolom_type_pvb").Value ' calculated field column number for chosen type


With Worksheets("Opvolging PVB").Range("xreferentie") ' xreferentie is the range of data columns
    If mkeuze = "" And mtype = "" Then
        Range("xreferentie").AutoFilter
    Else
        Range("xreferentie").AutoFilter
        If mkeuze <> "" Then
            .AutoFilter field:=mkolom_bgl, Criteria1:="x"
        End If
        If mtype <> "" Then
            .AutoFilter field:=mkolom_type, Criteria1:=mtype
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

When run on another PC there are several different error messages like:

> Method Autofilter of Object Range failed (command shown: Selection.Autofilter)

or

> Method Select of Object Range failed (command shown: Select("B1")

Comment: Format of VBA code not correct

Comment: The `Range()` calls inside the `With` block are not scoped to the block using a leading `.`  If those ranges are in some *other* sheet then you should be explicit about which sheet.  Also there's no "Select(B1)" in your posted code, so is there other code which might be causing the error messages?

Comment: Inside your `With` statement, change the `Range("xreferentie").AutoFilter` to just `.AutoFilter`.